# Capture screen shot programmatically in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-dialog

I have a `GridView` to show images. Every image click show the list activity as dialog based on same position. When I click the back button, I need to capture a screen shot of the list activity. How can I do this?

Here is an example to work, but it doesn't capture the list activity as dialog activity.

```
View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap bm = v1.getDrawingCache();
BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(bm);             
holder.cardBack.setBackgroundDrawable(bitmapDrawable);
// holder.cardBack.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.a);
holder.rootLayout.startAnimation(flipAnimation);
```

Comment: check this link ,Hope it helps you 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661536/how-to-programatically-take-a-screenshot-on-android

Comment: @RajeshM Ok thanks. this code has work. i have created activity as dialog. how can i capture front of screen. how can apply imageview on gridview

Answer (score 0):

try this, 
Call this method, passing in the outer most ViewGroup that you want a screen shot of:

```
public Bitmap screenShot(View view) {
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(),
            view.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    view.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
}
```

Ref : [How to programmatically take a screenshot in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661536/how-to-programatically-take-a-screenshot-on-android)